# ERROR while giving future GRANTs to a schema in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting below error while giving future grants on a schema to role.

`future grant with privilege OWNERSHIP on object type TABLE already exists in the schema.`

below is the command using
`GRANT OWNERSHIP ON FUTURE TABLES IN SCHEMA dev.con TO ROLE RL_DEV;`

i have checked the future grants for this role but nothing is present.

any suggestions would be appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "*i have checked the future grants for this role but nothing is present.*" How *exactly* did you check? Can you share the process which you followed/code you executed to check such future grants, and what the output of that was? Snowflake seems to directly disagree with your assertion.

Comment: `show future grants in schema <schema_name>;`
this query gives future grants if exists any, ownership already present to a role but i tried to give ownership to another role it is giving this eror.
`future grant with privilege OWNERSHIP on object type TABLE already exists in the schema.`